# Usually plugins will include wp-config.php or wp-load.php in order to gain access to core WordPress functions

Tags: php, wordpress

In my php file I use `require_once('../../../wp-load.php');`
but it's not the correct form to call to Wordpress functions...

Are there much better ways to do this?

Comment: can u plz explain more.what u need.??

Comment: In My plugin I called wp-load.php. but wordpress admins says me to change including this file ... they said me that we dont know direction to this file thats why we can't call this.. now I can't choose the right way how can I call the wordpress functions without using this

Comment: Try this  function load_wp(){
    global $wpdb;
    include_once('wp-load.php');
}

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me.. They sent me the link to undestand how can i solve this problem, but i don't understand .. please can you explain me?